# Shopify - Getting A 422 Unprocessible Entity In Url_CallBack Response

Tags: c#, shopify

Im trying to send a callback notification for my hosted payment gateway but I'm getting a "422 Unprocessable Entity"  response. When I try to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and setting up the same values(that got a 422 response), it is working well that I'm getting a "200 OK" response, so does the payment status of my product is changing to "Paid".  This is the generated code snippet that I copied from the Postman.

```
string strBuilder = "x_account_id=" + account_id;
strBuilder += "&x_reference=" + reference;
strBuilder += "&x_currency=" + currency;
strBuilder += "&x_test=" + test;
strBuilder += "&x_amount=" + amount;
strBuilder += "&x_gateway_reference=" + gateway_reference;
strBuilder += "&x_timestamp=" + timestamp;
strBuilder += "&x_result=" + resultcode;
strBuilder += "&x_signature=" + signature;

Response.Write("strBuilder : " + strBuilder);

var client = new RestClient(url_callback);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", strBuilder, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Response.Write("Response : " + response.ResponseStatus + " " + response.StatusCode);
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Try using JSON format instead of form data format.